# HTML Character Encoding to accept UTF-8

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a website for a client who's located in Brazil. A section of his website shows feedback/reviews from users.

Here is an example:

**Correct Version:**

"Três aprovados em menos de dois minutos!"

When I output to the user, this is whats showing:

**Incorrect Version:**

"TrÃªs aprovados em menos de dois minutos!"

I'm saving these reviews to a mySQL database (Hostgator) and I've set my database collation to "utf8_unicode_ci".

At the top of my HTML decument, I've declared this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" class="fixed">
<head>
    <title>@yield("title")</title>
    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Rest of the page is here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Laravel 5 to grab my data from the DB and I display it like so:

```
{{ mb_convert_encoding($feedback->message, "UTF-8") }}
```

Funny thing is, if I use the code above on my localhost, the correct "review"
is shown. But once I upload it to hostgator, the "review" is not shown correctly.

If I change it to "{{ mb_convert_encoding($feedback->message, "auto") }}", the correct "review" is shown on uploaded page but on my localhost, the wrong "review" is shown.

I've never ran into this issue before!
<s>When I get phpinfo on the clients hostgator page, it shows that "default_charset" is set to "null"</s>

Could that be the issue?

Thanks!

#### UPDATE

I've fixed the "default_charset" to "UTF-8" and I still have the same issue.

Here's the response header

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 18 Sep 2015 19:36:29 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=75
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=[hidden]; expires=Fri, 18-Sep-2015 21:36:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=[hidden]; expires=Fri, 18-Sep-2015 21:36:29 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Heres my Database Configuration:

```
 PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: show your response headers - that could be modifying it.

Comment: besides setting collation, the charset must also be set; both on the db/tables, and on the connection. Best is to use utf-8 everywhere.
Default charset null could be it, it defaults to 'C' (basically ASCII). What happens if you drop the mb_convert_encoding alltogether?

Comment: If I drop "mb_convert_encoding" it displays properly on my localhost but not on the public version. I'm guessing its a configuration on hostgators end.

Comment: Have you read [***UTF-8 All The Way Through***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236)? That will solve your issue.

Comment: Also [***This Laravel Post***](https://phplaravel.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/using-mysql-utf8mb4-character-set-and-collation-with-laravel/) will help you A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` and put this on the header `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for the input but no luck :( I'm using Laravel to do all database fetches. I've updated my original post with my database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with spanish characters not showing properly using hostgator hosting and I solved by changing the character set to UTF-8 of the document itself on the text editor, PSPad on my case. Check the image:

[image]